# is it possible to make a email bot that replies accordingly?

Tags: email, artificial-intelligence, bots

so i was wondering if its possible to make a email bot that reads mails and reply accordingly?
It should work like an enhanced chat bot.
I have googled but came across nothing.
Any platform/technology will work.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is better separated into its parts, try breaking the task down into 3 separate subtasks.

**part 1 - hook emails into an API**

I suggest looking at something like MailGun: https://www.mailgun.com/

**part 2 - use chatbot logic to determine an appropriate reply**

A good example of a versatile chatbot is here:
https://www.pandorabots.com/

**part 3 - use an emailer script to compile and send a reply**

Which you can then do using MailGun, or something more generic like PHPMailer

---

All in all once you have used something like mailgun to receive the email, it can be stored in a database or parsed as JSON. From here you can do whatever kind of manipulation you want based on requirements. Something more autonomous would parse that JSON into a chatbot to determine the reply then send off the reply right away. Something a little more manual would be to store the email into a database, then use a cron job to pick up new emails at an interval (every x seconds/minutes/hours/etc) and process the chatbox and reply logic from there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is pandora bot same as watson conversation?Will there be any difference if i use either of them for emails?

Comment: ultimately you can use whichever conversation/chatbot that works well for you. The important thing is separating out the 3 parts of what you're trying to do. 1) receive the email, 2) apply chatbot logic, 3) send reply.